# update column from another column with conditional

Tags: postgresql

I have `table1` and `tbl_cat`. I want to update value of `x` where `animal` is `cat`

```
table1
id    id_animal    animal    x
2          1        cat      3
3          2        cat      5
4          1        dog      7
5          2        dog      8
6          3        dog      9

tbl_cat
id    x
1    10
2    30
```

Result Expectation:

```
table1
id    id_animal    animal    x
2          1        cat      10
3          2        cat      30
4          1        dog      7
5          2        dog      8
6          3        dog      9
```

I use this query, but it's not work:

```
update table1
set table1.x = tbl_cat.x  
from table1 inner join tbl_cat
on (table1.id_animal=tbl_cat.id)
where table1.animal='cat'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct syntax in Postgres is:

```
update table1
    set table1.x = tbl_cat.x  
    from tbl_cat
    where table1.id_animal = tbl_cat.id and
          table1.animal = 'cat';
```

For some inexplicable reason, the three major databases that support `join` in update clauses (MySQL, SQL Server, and Postgres) all have different syntax.  Your syntax is the SQL Server syntax.

Comment: "*For some inexplicable reason*" - I guess that's because the SQL standard does not define any join for an UPDATE at all.

Comment: I use your way. But I get an error : ERROR: table name "table1" specified more than once

Comment: I get my fault. I wrote `from table1`. I fix using your query. Thank you :)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name . . . Believe it or not, database developers are usually not quite that creative.  Two different ways of doing something is common (`substr()`/ `substring()`; `len()`/``length()`; `grouping sets`/`grouping_sets`; `datepart()`/`extract()`;  etc.  Three ways is much less common, particularly for general-purpose functionality (there are other examples).

Comment: @GordonLinoff: Hmm... three ways to do outer joins (Oracle, SQL Server, SQL Standard). Three ways to quote objects (MySQL, SQL Server, SQL Standard). Four ways to define "auto increments". ( `serial`, `identity`, `auto_increment`, SQL Standard). (At least) three ways to retrieve the next sequence value (Postgres, Oracle, SQL Standard) - there are other examples ;)